# php loop recordset until

Tags: php, mysql, loops, while-loop

In php, how can I loop a mysql recordset until ive found the criteria I need?

is it just:

```
$sql_result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table", $db); 
while ($rs = mysql_fetch_array($sql_result) && $done == 0) {
    if (this == that) { $done = 1; }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (this == that) { break; }
```

Simply break out of the loop, it'll stop running and carry on with the rest of the code.

Answer (score 1):

The immediately obvious answer is the following:

```
$sql_result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table", $db); 
while ($rs = mysql_fetch_array($sql_result) && $done == 0) {
    if (this == that) {
        break;
    }
}

carry_on();
```

Is there something you can do with your query though? To make it just get the correct result for you? What is it you're actually doing with your `this == that` condition?

Answer (score 0):

That's pretty much it - see the other answers for ending that search.  Also consider adjusting your query to select the specific record you're looking for.  Letting the database handle the search will be much faster/more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

That should work, but you can also do:

```
$sql_result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table", $db); 
while ($rs = mysql_fetch_array($sql_result)) {
  if (this == that) { 
    break;
  }
}
```